# Use specs2 matchers in an Around block

Tags: scala, specs2

How does one run matchers from a separate class's function in an Around block in specs2?

Example (using Play framework):

```
class Spec extends Specification {
  "the application" should {
    "do something" in new WithBrowser { // <-- 1. because of this around block
      val runner = new Runner
      runner.check(browser)
    }
  }
}

class Runner extends MustMatchers {
  def check(browser: TestBrowser) = {
    browser.pageSource must contain("some text that isn't there") // <-- 2. this won't fail
  }
}
```

I read in the Around scaladoc that it doesn't work with matchers that don't throw FailureExceptions. Does this mean I have to check all the matchers myself? How else can I have my matchers fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By extending `MustMatchers` you unfortunately managed to avoid bringing in the all-important `MustThrownExpectations` trait, which has the following documentation:

```
/**
* This trait provides implicit definitions to transform any value into a 
* MustExpectable, throwing exceptions when a match fails
*/
```

If you follow all of the Specs2 traits all the way down from `mutable.Specification`, there's a trait `MustThrownMatchers` which will fail "the right way" for your use case; i.e.:

```
class ThrowingRunner extends MustThrownMatchers {
  def check(browser: TestBrowser) = {
    browser.pageSource must contain("some text that isn't there")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works (ie it fails). Do I need to wait some time before accepting the answer?

Comment: That's up to you. Perhaps someone will come up with a solution that's even cleaner than adding 6 characters to your code? ;-)